# Different _fileName values in Visual Studio debug watch

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, openscenegraph

std::string filename;

In this code:`osg::Image* image = osgDB::readImageFile(filename + ".dicom");`

osg::Image type variable: image gets wrong returned values from read file. And by debugging to the line above, the watch window shows as follows:
[image]

The _fileName (std::string type) value indicated on the first and second lines are both "digest", but in the fourth line the value of _fileName turned out to be "iiiiii\x*6" with capacity equals to 0.

According to my understanding, the _fileName of the fourth line in the watch window should indicate the same member variable of osg::Image as the _fileName on the first and second lines. Thus, I think all the _fileName in the debug watch window should have the same value. But, I am not sure why there are such differences.

Comment: It looks like there are two members named _fileName in two separate classes.

Comment: if `filename` (as a parameter to function `readImageFile`) is `char *` then you're trying to add two pointers (`filename` and `".dicom"`), and if so, the result could be undefined

Comment: the filename and _fileName are both std::string type

Comment: Can you load & visualize the image? Is it a wrong image?

Comment: What does "Raw view" show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC++ implementation of `std::string` uses different storage strategies for short strings and for long ones. Short strings (16 bytes or less) are stored in a buffer embedded directly inside the `std::string` object (you will see it as `_Bx._Buf` in Raw View). Long strings are stored in an independently-allocated block of memory located elsewhere (pointed by `_Bx._Ptr`).

If you violate the integrity of `std::string` object, you might easily end up in a situation as the one you describe. The objects thinks that the data should be stored in the external buffer, but in reality it is stored in the internal one and vice-versa. That might easily confuse the debugger as well.

I suggest you open the Raw View of your `std::string` object and check what it shows in `_Bx._Buf` and `_Bx._Ptr`. If the current `_Myres` value is smaller or equal to the internal buffer size, then the data is [supposed to be] stored in the internal buffer. Otherwise, it is stored in the external memory block. See if this invariant really holds. If it doesn't, then there's your problem. Then you'll just have to find at which point it got broken.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason your filename argument isn't getting .dicom attached to it when it becomes _filename ("digest" should become "digest.dicom"). OSG decides which plugin to use for file loading by extension, so it will have no idea how to load the current one.  And so the second reference to _filename doesn't get intialized by any plugin.

By the way, I don't think the dicom plugin is part of the standard OSG prebuilt package - you might have to gather the dependencies yourself and build the plugin.